# TPM module for my DELL 1720

Tags: dell-inspiron, bitlocker, tpm

I am trying to install bit locker on my Dell 1720. Does anyone know if it has a TPM modulee? I had a look in BIOS, but couldn't find anything related to the TPM module. But it does have some sort of HDD Password option that I can set in the BIOS.

Is this equivalent in security to bit locker? I dug up and looked at the receipt/spec sheet but can't find anything about the TPM module in there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by looking at the technical specs of your notebook i would think that it does not support TPM:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/ins1720/en/om_en/html/specs.htm#wp1102222

i can't find anything related to TPM in the rest of the documenation to that product as well.

Comment: Hmm.. so what about the HDD Password in BIOS? Is it as good as bit locker or other TPG based encryption or just a waste of time?

Comment: i would say: waste of time.